# Calculating individual width between buildings using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.5, proximity

I have a building footprint shapefile and I would like to calculate the individual width between each building (i.e., adjacent building and across the street). I have looked at solutions which use the road network but they turned out to be unfeasible as some areas do not have roads.

Is there any way to use the Near tool or other tools to achieve this?

Using the Euclidian distance tool with the building footprint as input, I have generated a raster with a cell size of 1. I am now hoping to find a more accurate and less visual solution to generate data on gaps between buildings.